# How can you ensure your alignment will not be damaged from potholes?

Tags: alignment

uk Roads have gone so bad now there are pot holes everywhere.

So as not to have to do an alignment what can I do avoid this?

I imagine drive slowly in which case what would be a safe speed for potholes?

Also maybe drive on main roads where potholes tend to be less.

Comment: I hit a large hole at 40mph... no damage as the suspension did not have much time to move and it was a LandRover...

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this would have to be quite variable. Depends on the pot hole, depends on the type of road (small road vs highway, etc.) traffic conditions, et al.

The most obvious answer is to avoid them as much as possible. After that, make sure you're diligent to spot them, then maintain proper tire pressure and pick your angles properly. I'd look at it kind of like off-road driving; not every path through the pot hole will provide the same shock.

Other than driving habit or technique (which is off topic here), youd be looking at vehicle modifications. Things like upgrading tires and suspension would be the main answers, but they would be extreme answers to address pot holes.

Comment: So 40" wheels, 30" of suspension travel and no problem then... :)

Comment: @SolarMike Exactly! Baja baby! :)