# Arr cars with lowered suspension more susceptible to getting misaligned than those without?

Tags: suspension, alignment

Are cars which have lowered suspensions more susceptible to getting misaligned due to potholes etc than one which is at a normal ride height?

Comment: see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/72347/10976

Comment: Depends on the quality of bag job, I have done many that have no alignment issues and still have plenty of suspension travel to handle potholes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, considerably more so. The whole point of the suspension it to allow the car to absorb bumps and holes in the road - by lowering it you're reducing it's ability to do so. You're also changing the angles of various parts of the suspension, meaning the forces aren't being transmitted in the direction the manufacturer intended, increasing the likelihood of something bending or breaking.

There's a good reason why vehicles designed for off-road use have much higher suspension!

Comment: The reason why off-road vehicles have higher suspension is for more ground clearance, and more suspension travel, allowing the vehicle to retain traction on more uneven ground surfaces.

Comment: @Kitsunemimi one of the reasons - the increased suspension travel also helps to absorb impacts better...